# Does VPN allow multiple devices connected to the same router to have more then 1 IP?

Tags: vpn

Lets say i have 2 devices conected to the same internet provider trough a router. Can those 2 devices have 2 diferent internet/wan ip at the same time ? If so, can you indicate a vpn that does that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"VPN" by it self does not give you an IP address. It tunnels and encrypts your traffic to a dedicated server, belonging to VPN provider, creating [V]ritual [P]rivate [N]etwork between your device and server. Your device external IP depends on the server through which it reaches a (for example) web service.

If two different devices are tunneled to the same server, they will have the same IP adress. If they are tunneled to different servers - they will have different IPs.

---

While the above is how it usually works, some VPN providers may be configured differently. To be 100% sure, you have to read the provider's documentation, EULA, or other license agreements.